# fmt.Println prints out format verbs like %s

Tags: go

I've written code that is intended to print out keys and values in a map.

```
kvs := map[string]string{"a": "apple", "b": "banana"}
for k, v := range kvs {
    fmt.Println("%s -> %s\n", k, v)
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
a -> apple
b -> banana
```

But the output is actually:

```
%s -> %s
a apple
%s -> %s
b banana
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use string formatters, which aren't supported by `fmt.Println`.

According to the [godocs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> Printf formats according to a format specifier

whereas

> Println formats using the default formats

The following will give the output you are trying to get:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    kvs := map[string]string{
        "a": "apple",
        "b": "banana",
    }
    for k, v := range kvs {
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %s\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

Note that maps in Go do not have a specific ordering so you may get any arbitrary key-value pair before another.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong printing function.

I) Try to replace `Println` with `Printf` and it should work fine.

II) Another option is to first format the string `s := fmt.Sprintf("a %s", "string")` and then print it `fmt.Println(s)`.

reference: [Go by Example: String Formatting](https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting)